# How can I make an iframe that fits the size of its content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

what happens is that I have an iframe that brings results from a link, the width of the iframe will always be the same, but depending on the number of results the height of the iframe varies, so I would like to know how I can do to adjust the size of the iframe each time the results are displayed without having a scroll.

Comment: can you control the parent frame?

Comment: if so, you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between frames. for the iframe, use `window.parent.postMessage(…)` to send the dimensions of the iframe onload and onresize events. the parent frame can use `window.addEventListener("message", event => …)`, check for the message coming from the iframe, and resize the iframe accordingly.

Comment: No, I have no control over the parent frame :c

Comment: the parent controls the size of its iframes

Comment: Anyway, could you give me an example of how to implement it as you say please?

Comment: Sure, i added an answer but it's not going to be much help to you unless you control the parent frame.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide source code and it's difficult to realize what's your problem.

However try this solution to make the iframe take the width and height of your browser.

ex :

css :

```
        html,body{
            width:100%;
            height:100vh;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            border:none;
        }
        iframe{
            width:100%;
            height:100vh;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            border:none;
        }
```

Html :

```
        <iframe src="https://blogger.com" name="otherSite"></iframe>
```

You have to do a copy and paste of the code because it cannot run in a snippet.

Comment: _"depending on the number of results the height of the iframe varies"_, so no the frame shouldn't be `100vh`. _"I would like to know how I can do to adjust the size of the iframe each time the results are displayed without having a scroll."_ the question is how to dynamically size the iframe based on its contents.

Comment: yeah, what I need is to dynamically size the iframe based on its content

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to imagine without a part of reproducible code...

Answer (score 0):

An iframe cannot set its own size, it is determined and controlled by the parent window. This is particularly important because an iframe's source may be part of another domain. It would be a security risk to allow an external domain to control our domain. Read the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) documentation carefully to ensure proper message handling between frames -

**parent.html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      // when message is received … 
      // if it is from our trusted origin …
      // and the message is an object …
      // and the message type is "resize" …
      // then resize the iframe 
      window.addEventListener("message", event => {
        if (event.origin != "http://example.org") return
        if (typeof event.data != "object") return
        if (event.data.type != "resize") return
        const iframe = window.frames.myframe 
        iframe.setAttribute("width", event.data.width)
        iframe.setAttribute("height", event.data.height)
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    my content…
    <iframe name="myframe" src="/myframe.html" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**myframe.html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      // sendSize function
      // get the width and height of the document
      // and post the values to the parent frame
      function sendSize() {
        window.parent.postMessage(
          {
            type: "resize",
            width: document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
            height: document.documentElement.scrollHeight
          },
          "http://example.org"
        )
      }

      // when this window loads or resizes …
      // call our sendSize function
      window.addEventListener("load", sendSize)
      window.addEventListener("resize", sendSize)
    <script>
  </head>
  <body>
    …
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anyway thank you very much, this kind of answers also help me to learn new things c: