# How can I made an HTML file call code from other HTML files, i.e. keep everything modular?

Tags: javascript, html, modularity

I'm trying to convert my personal notes to HTML and keep them modularized. I'm trying to get this test code to work.

I have a file called called main-file.html.

I have another file called sub-file.html. The only code within this file is "Hello World".

I want to double click on the main-file.html such that when it opens up in my web browser, I see a page with the words "Hello World" on it, because the main-file.html is reading the code from sub-file.html and rendering it, as though that code were within main-file.html itself. Eventually, I want to reference numerous subfiles.

What is the simplest code that will achieve this result? Using JavaScript is acceptable. I do not want to use 3rd party software, PHP, SSI, web servers, etc. because I want this to work on any computer out of the box with just a web browser. I also don't want to use iFrames or objects, because I've tried for days to get this to work for my application and I can't get it to render properly without lots of awkward scrollbars, etc. (unless you know of a way to render each sub-file one after the other without scrollbars, which I couldn't figure out). I just want the main-file.html to read the code within sub-file.html and treat it as though sub-file.html's code was within main-file.html.

I've been working for days with Google Bard and ChatGPT trying to get this to work, with no success. Any help is very much appreciated.

I tried this code, with no success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
        // Use JavaScript to load and display content from sub-file.html
        fetch('sub-file.html')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading sub-file.html:', error);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"...because I want this to work on any computer out of the box with just a web browser"` ~ I don't think AJAX will be suitable for you then either

Comment: `I tried this code, with no success.` No succes how?? Errors ? what? Are you running from file://somefolder/main-file.html?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I am trying to from the files directly. Just double clicking on the HTML files. I want to keep everything as simply as humanly possible.

Comment: You cannot do fetch from file://.  Instead use an iFrame and have it [resize itself to content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921567/how-can-i-make-an-iframe-that-fits-the-size-of-its-content)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without JavaScript using `iframe` to load your subpage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="content" src="sub-file.html" width="100%" height="300">
</body>
</html>
```

The only limit is that you have to set a specific height, if the content of the subpage is longer it will appear in the scrollbar.

The reason you can't use JavaScript to do this is for the CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) policy that prevents you to call directly a file.

### **EDIT**

You can set the iframe at the same height of the browser height. Thanks to [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) for pointing it out in the comments.

**HTML + CSS**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="content" src="sub-file.html" style="width:100%; min-height:300px; height: 100vh;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I don't know the height of each iframe. All my sub-notes are different in size.

Comment: The iFrame can resize itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921567/how-can-i-make-an-iframe-that-fits-the-size-of-its-content

Comment: And if you add `name="iframe"` then all links in main can have `target="iframe"`

Comment: @mplungjan Alright, I'll look into resizing. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your code will work only if you execute it into a web server. If you execute it in a web browser like a file, it will gives you an exception.

Personally I put my HTML notes in single files.